# Pygame, line throught points stored in 2 arrays

Tags: python, pygame

I have two arrays containing points for a line to go through. One array has ten random elements defining the x values,  and the other has ten elements defining the y values.

Using Pygame, how should I draw the lines?

Answer (score 5):

Use the [zip](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) method to combine your lists to a list of points

---

**Example**

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))

x = (0, 100, 200, 300)
y = (300, 100, 20, 50)

points = zip(x, y)
last = None
for p in points:
    if last:
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (255,255,0), last, p)
        print last, p
    last = p

pygame.display.flip()
```

**Result:**

> (0, 300) (100, 100)
>   (100, 100) (200, 20)
>   (200, 20) (300, 50)

[image]